# Identity from multivariable calculus, possibly Taylor expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis

I am working through Theorem 3.24. in Nonlinear Optimization Andrzej Ruszczynski, which includes a step I do not understand:

Let $x, x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x_k \to x$ for $k \to \infty$, and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.

Then, for a certain sequence $\alpha_k$:
$$
f(x_k) - f(x) = \triangledown f(x) \cdot (x_k - x) + \alpha_k
$$
where
$\frac{\alpha_k}{\lVert x_k - x \rVert} \to 0$, as $k \to \infty$.

It is not clear to me why this is true, even though I can intuitively see why it might be.
Is it perhaps some multivariate version of the Taylor expansion involving the directional derivative?

Comment: This is equivalent to the limit definition of the derivative in several variables.

Comment: This follows from the first order Taylor approximation. Usually the $\alpha_k$ is denoted $o\!\left(\|x_k-x\|\right)$ (see [little "o" notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)).